# How can I pause my program inside a for(;;) loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, espeak

I have a for loop inside my program that there is a call to `espeak` engin inside it:

The text is given by the other app and is different in every cycle of loop, and I am trying to get this text, pass it to espeak, it says the text, and the rest of the code will running(printing the given text for example).

But the problem is that, when espeak is talking, the rest of code doesn't wait till it ends the speaking, and I am looking for a way to pause the program till the espeak ends, then rest of the code will execute, but don't know how?

```
            #include <string.h>
            #include <malloc.h>
            #include <espeak/speak_lib.h>

            espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
            espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
            char *path=NULL;
            int Buflength = 1000, Options=0;
            void* user_data;
            t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
            espeak_PARAMETER Parm;
            char Voice[] = {"English"};
            unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;

        espeak_init()
        {
                output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;
                espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, Options ); 
                espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
                const char *langNativeString = "en";
                espeak_VOICE voice = {0};
              //  memset(&voice, 0, sizeof(espeak_VOICE));
                    voice.languages = langNativeString;
                    voice.name = "US";
                    voice.variant = 2;
                    voice.gender = 1;
                    espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(&voice);
                Size = strlen(text)+1;    
        } 

int main()
{   
       for(;;)
        {
            ...
            espeak_Synth( text, Size, position, position_type, end_position, flags,unique_identifier, user_data );
            espeak_Synchronize( );
            // REST OF THE CODE...PRINTING THE WORLD THAT ESPEAK SAID FOR EXAMPLE
            printf("\n %s \n", text);
            ...

        }
}
```

Comment: Usually this is accomplished through synchronization efforts, like trying to obtain a lock that isn't released until the other function is finished

Comment: usually async is more complicated than synchronous calls. Are you sure that there is no blocking version of the speech method?

Comment: What does your call to `espeak_Initialize` look like?  Looks like you should set `AUDIO_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS`

Comment: As what @NathanOliver suggested, look how espeak_Initialize was called, you may need to use `AUDIO_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS` as the output mode.

Comment: @KerrekSB OP asked for a way to pause the loop

Comment: Doesn't espeak_Synchronize do just that?

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne sometimes what the Asker asks is not what they needed to ask. The asker needs synchronization. Inserting a voodoo sleep instruction might work now, but historically this approach has an annoying tendency to result in even harder to find bugs in the future. Solve the problem where possible. Hide it only as a last resort.

Comment: @user4581301 I got your point of view, im going to remove my commentary. Thanks

Comment: @NathanOliver: I lost my internet connection till now, I updated my question

Comment: @user3486308 Did you try setting the `AUDIO_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS` flag in `espeak_Initialize`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes but didn't work! had no effect

Comment: It appears that you do not check the return value of `espeak_Synth`  It's possible that subsequent calls are calling EE_BUFFER_FULL or some other error.

Comment: @Wyck: I have no error. look at this for the real problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359223/how-to-stop-listening-till-the-espeak-ends-speaking